# Gain login access / data from an Android phone with broken motherboard?

Tags: android, mobile, google

My phone's motherboard died beyond repair, so I am thinking of selling it as broken. There is no real sensitive data in that phone except that I am logged in the phone's Google account as well as browser's Gmail.

My question is, will the buyer (or whoever gets the phone someday) be able to access my Google account by replacing the motherboard or with any other uncommon methods (i.e., USB, etc)?

Comment: What model is the phone? Newer Android phones have encryption enabled by default for this very reason.

Comment: How about changing your Google account password?

Comment: @Johnny it's just a "china" android phone, not a popular brand

Comment: @Limit Will that invalidate the browser session in Gmail on that phone?